# Metodo POST en Spring Boot con datos relacionales

Tags: api, spring, spring-boot, post, spring-mvc

estoy empezando con las apis en Spring Boot, cree la base de datos desde Spring y una de ellas tiene relacion, cuando envio el metodo post, me inserta en la base se datos sin ningun problema, pero el dato que relaciona la tabla se lo estoy enviando pero me aparece en null, saben por que podria ser?

unicamente me pasa con el "id_dependencia" que es el valor que relaciona con la otra tabla pero  al enviarlo es el unico que me aparece en null, como la imagen de postman

envio post desde postman

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi tengo mi modelo

```html
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "usuarios")
public class Usuarios {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @JoinColumn(name="id_dependencia", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Dependencias dependencias;
    
    private String nombres;
    private String apellidos;
    private String email;
    private String rol;
    private String tipo;
    private Boolean activo;
    
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Dependencias getDependencias() {
        return dependencias;
    }
    public void setDependencias(Dependencias dependencias) {
        this.dependencias = dependencias;
    }
    public String getNombres() {
        return nombres;
    }
    public void setNombres(String nombres) {
        this.nombres = nombres;
    }
    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }
    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getRol() {
        return rol;
    }
    public void setRol(String rol) {
        this.rol = rol;
    }
    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }
    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }
    public Boolean getActivo() {
        return activo;
    }
    public void setActivo(Boolean activo) {
        this.activo = activo;
    }
```

y mi metodo post

```html
    @Override
    public Usuarios doPost(@RequestBody Usuarios ObjectT, Principal principal) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        usuarioService.saveUsuario(ObjectT);
        return ObjectT;
    
    }
```

gracias si me pueden guiar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo resolvi de esta forma:

en mi caso tengo una tabla EMPRESA relacionada a una tabla USUARIO y cuando me llega el objeto USUARIO trae solamente el IdEMPRESA, los campos NombreEmpresa y Otros vienen vacios, entonces lo que hago es hacer un busqueda de la empresa y asignarsela al usuario de nuevo. No se si es correcto o existe un metodo directo, pero asi me funciona muy bien.

```
Empresa empresa = EmpresaService.buscarPorId(usuario.getEmpresa().getIdEmpresa());
usuario.setEmpresa(empresa);
```

En tu caso seria algo asi:

```
Dependencias dependencias = dependenciaService.buscarPorID(ObjectT.dependencias.getId());
ObjectT.setDependencias(dependencias);
```